# java.lang.NullPointerException Wallpaper Android

Tags: android, bitmap

He notado un error a través de Bloqueos y errores ANR de la *Play Store*, que le esta sucediendo a muchas personas, a mi todos los testeos nunca me ha sucedido ningún error, siempre me coloca los wallpapers y todo funciona de maravilla, pero por lo visto a muchos les da el error:

> ```
> java.lang.NullPointerException:    at
> android.app.WallpaperManager.setBitmap (WallpaperManager.java:1289)  
> at android.app.WallpaperManager.setBitmap (WallpaperManager.java:1261)
> at android.app.WallpaperManager.setBitmap (WallpaperManager.java:1234)
> at android.app.WallpaperManager.setBitmap (WallpaperManager.java:1200)
> at com.test.wall.infowall$SetWallpaperTask.onPostExecute
> (infowall.java:188)   at
> com.test.wall.infowall$SetWallpaperTask.onPostExecute
> (infowall.java:131)   at android.os.AsyncTask.finish
> (AsyncTask.java:695)   at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600
> (AsyncTask.java:180)   at
> android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage
> (AsyncTask.java:712)   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage
> (Handler.java:106)   at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:193)   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6880)   at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)   at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
> (RuntimeInit.java:504)   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
> (ZygoteInit.java:858)
> ```

Mi codigo *infowall.java* es el siguiente, en él indico la **línea 188**, que da el error:

```
public class SetWallpaperTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    String image_url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("img2");

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        Bitmap result= null;



        try {
            result = Picasso.get()
                    .load(image_url)
                    .get();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (result != null) {
            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
            int height = metrics.heightPixels;
            int width = metrics.widthPixels;
            Log.e("Width", "" + width);
            Log.e("height", "" + height);
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(result, width, height, true);
            WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            wallpaperManager.setWallpaperOffsetSteps(1, 1);
            wallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);
            try {
                wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute () {
        super.onPreExecute();

        if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(infowall.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.proceso));
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute (Bitmap result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getBaseContext());
        try {

                wallpaperManager.setBitmap(result);  <--- LINEA 188

                progressDialog.dismiss();

                Toast toast3 = new Toast(getApplicationContext());

                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout,
                        (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.lytLayout));

                TextView txtMsg = layout.findViewById(R.id.txtMensaje);
                txtMsg.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.wallyes));


                toast3.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 20, 20);
                toast3.setView(layout);
                toast3.show();

                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.wallyes), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Creo que esta relacionado con el resultado del Bitmap, pero ni idea. Si me pudieran orientar a que se deberá dicho error, se los agradecería, de antemano Bendiciones a todos.

Comment: Te recomendaría mirar el código de WallpaperManager (si, en android) para saber cual podría ser el problema.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que noto es que tratas de obtener el valor de la imagen dentro del Asynctask lo cual es incorrecto:

```
public class SetWallpaperTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

String image_url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("img2");

...
...

}
```

**La obtención de datos debe realizarse dentro de `onCreate()`** de la activity que recibe la información, obtén la url y úsala en tu `AsyncTask`.

```
    private  String image_url;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String image_url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("img2");
        ...
        ...
        
   }
```

Comment: vale eleanys testeo y te aviso